# Is there a way to use something similar to a capture group for apache2 server name

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, redirect

I have a server that sits behind an AWS load balancer. The LB can't do automatic redirect from HTTP to HTTPs, and the LB is doing my SSL. So I need to setup apache on my servers to redirect any request on port 80 to `https://FOOBAR` m where `FOOBAR` is the domain that came in. I haven't been able to find a way of doing that so far. I'm an apache newb though.

What I'm trying to do is something similar to this. I'll use regex as an example

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName (.*)
   Redirect / https://\1
</VirtualHost>
```

If there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

---

EDIT: Sorry I should have explained why this is happening. I actually have a tomcat server running my app on port 8080, and the LB points to that. From what I can tell so far my requests come in on http (which is expected), but when my app server sends redirects (for login purposes) it tries to redirect to http, instead of https. I haven't had a chance to fully investigate this, but I wanted to work around it for now by point the LB to point to the apache server, and have any port 80 requests redirect to 443.

---

EDIT2: The other reason I'm interested in doing this, is that since the LB can't do the redirect, I need to have another redirect mechanism in place to tell the browser to go to `https://FOOBAR`

Comment: IIRC in apache 2.2 you can define a default virtual host with `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` and otherwise the first VirtualHost entry is the default for all requests not matching an explicitely defined ServerName or ServerAlias further along in your config. 

But if your load balancer is doing the SSL offloading , all requests hitting apache will be plain http, and never https, right?

Comment: Since the ELB is doing SSL termination, *all* connection will reach apache on port 80. You can't use this to trigger the redirect. Instead, inspect the X-Forwarded-Proto header.